# Python + Regex + UTF-8 doesn't recognize accents

Tags: python, regex, utf-8

My problem is that Python, using regex and re.search() doesn't recognize accents even though I use utf-8. Here is my string of code;

```
#! /usr/bin/python
-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

htmlString = '</dd><dt> Fine, thank you.&#160;</dt><dd> Molt bé, gràcies.'

SearchStr = '(\<\/dd\>\<dt\>)+ ([\w+\,\.\s]+)([\&\#\d\;]+)(\<\/dt\>\<dd\>)+ (\w+) (\w+)'

Result = re.search(SearchStr, htmlString)

if Result:
print Result.groups()

passavol23:jO$ catalanword.py
('</dd><dt>', 'Fine, thank you.', '&#160;', '</dt><dd>', 'Molt', 'b')
```

So the problem is that it doesn't recognizes the é and thus stops. Any help would be appreciated. Im a Python beginner.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions and HTML, use a parser instead.

Comment: Also, regular expressions against raw bytes only match ASCII characters when using `\w`. You'd need to decode to Unicode and use the `re.UNICODE` switch instead, and even then there are many gaps in the Unicode support of the `re` module.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: or `re.LOCALE`.

Comment: @Junuxx: That depends too much the current locale settings of the machine you run the code on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `\w` only matches ascii characters, it translates to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. And matching UTF-8 bytes using regular expressions is hard enough, let alone only matching *word characters*, you'd have to match byte ranges instead.

You'll need to decode from UTF-8 to `unicode` and use the [`re.UNICODE` flag](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) instead:

```
>>> re.search(SearchStr, htmlString.decode('utf8'), re.UNICODE).groups()
(u'</dd><dt>', u'Fine, thank you.', u'&#160;', u'</dt><dd>', u'Molt', u'b\xe9')
```

However, you should really be using a HTML parser to deal with HTML instead. Use BeautifulSoup, for example. It'll handle encoding and Unicode correctly for you.