# Parsing through a text file with accentuated characters [Python]

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I'm trying to iterate through, and count the occurence of words in a text file in French (containing accentuated characters). The following code pick all the words, but doesn't consider accentuated characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-   import re

wordcount={}

f = open("verbatim2.txt", "r") regex = re.compile(r'\b\w{4,}\b')
#regex = re.compile(r'[A-Z]\p{L}+\s*')

for line in f:
    words = regex.findall(line)
    for word in words:
        print word
        if word not in wordcount:
            wordcount[word] = 1
        else:
            wordcount[word] += 1 for k,v in wordcount.items():
    print k, v
```

How to properly include accentuated characters in my "wordcount" dictionary?

Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate question - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245752/python-regex-utf-8-doesnt-recognize-accents

Comment: It seems very close indeed, but I can't see how to apply it to my problem

Comment: You are trying to count words of four or more characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code as closely as I could, (fixing syntax and usage errors), I got this to work. As stated above, this was already answered here [Python + Regex + UTF-8 doesn't recognize accents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245752/python-regex-utf-8-doesnt-recognize-accents)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-   
import re

wordcount={}

f = open("verbatim2.txt", "r")
regex = r'\b\w{4,}\b'
#regex = re.compile(r'[A-Z]\p{L}+\s*')

for line in f:
    words = re.findall(regex, line.decode('utf8'), re.UNICODE)
    for word in words:
        print word
        if word not in wordcount:
            wordcount[word] = 1
        else:
            for k,v in wordcount.items():
                wordcount[word] += 1
print wordcount
```

Answer (score 1):

Count/totalize/aggregate words of four or more characters without using a regular expression:

```
import collections
d = collections.counter()

with open('file') as f
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.split()
        words = (word for word in line if len(word) >= 4)
        d.update(words)
```

From the (v2.7) docs for `\w`:

> When the LOCALE and UNICODE flags are not specified, matches any
>   alphanumeric character and the underscore; this is equivalent to the
>   set [a-zA-Z0-9_]. With LOCALE, it will match the set [0-9_] plus
>   whatever characters are defined as alphanumeric for the current
>   locale. If UNICODE is set, this will match the characters [0-9_] plus
>   whatever is classified as alphanumeric in the Unicode character
>   properties database.

If you want to stick with the regex, add `flags = re.UNICODE`.